# Cannot open links in new tab with jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

Why I can't open a link in new tab on my mobile phone?
But when I tried running my script on the PC Desktop, that link can be opened in new tab..

This is my script

```
if($data[$flag] == 1){
    echo "<li><a href=\"img2.php?x=".$fix[0][0]."&y=".$fix[1][0]."\">Sektor ".($flag + 1)."</a></li>\n";}
    $flag++;
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it.

```
 if($data[$flag] == 1){
 echo "<li><a href=\"img2.php?x=".$fix[0][0]."&y=".$fix[1][0]."\" target="blank">Sektor ".($flag + 1)."</a></li>\n";}
$flag++;
```

**target="blank" use for open a link in new tab**

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but there is an error on the second line

Comment: just escape this part: \"blank\"

Answer (score 0):

To force a link to open up in a new window/tab, you can use target="_blank" on the URL like this:

```
if($data[$flag] == 1){
    echo "<li><a href=\"img2.php?x=".$fix[0][0]."&y=".$fix[1][0]."\" target="_blank">Sektor ".($flag + 1)."</a></li>\n";}
    $flag++;
```

This should result in output that looks something like this:

```
<li><a href="img2.php?x=123&y=1456" target="_blank">Sektor 789</a></li>
```

Do bear in mind that the underscore in '_blank' is important.

Also worth mentioning is that this was depreciated from XHTML 1.1, [but not from HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword).  This is a common misconception in the development community.